# What is LD50 for 25i (25I-NBOMe)?

Tags: pharmacology, toxicology

Firstly I would like to apologise if this is not correct place to ask this question, as it can be seen more as chemistry and not biology question.

I was looking around for data on psychedelic substance called `25i (25I-NBOMe)` . It was fist synthesized in 2003 and is somewhat 'new'. I have found some data on overdoses and they are few, however I could not find any specific data on mortality to dose rate nor on LD50 (Dose where 50% of people would die). [Wikipedia is quiet in this regard.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25I-NBOMe)
Judging by the dosage it being active in sub-milligram doses (600–1,200 µg) it should not be very lethal compared to most, should it?

**Where could I get data on LD50 for `25i (25I-NBOMe)`?**

Comment: Wiki is not quiet. It explicitly says the LD-50 has not been determined.

Comment: @daniel I know I have read that article before posting, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Cimbi-5 or 25i (25I-NBOMe) is a class 2C psychedelic drug.(wiki site.)

[image]

Lethal dose or LD50 of "Cimbi-5" is **still unknown**.

Though you can predict approximate the LD50 by [structure computationally](http://preadmet.bmdrc.org/).

Comment: Hi Das, I have registered moments ago to http://preadmet.bmdrc.org/ but can't see controls on toxicity 'drawer' nor on Chrome nor IE. If you have access to this tool could you do the prediction or help me on making it work on my machine. Thanks.